# Requires-clause appears after template template parameter: is this legal grammar?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Recently, I unexpectedly found that gcc and msvc accept the following code (notice the *requires-clause* in template-list):

```
#include <vector>

template <template <class> requires true class>
void f() {}

int main() {
  f<std::vector>();
}
```

and clang [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/8den7arj5) its grammar with:

```
<source>:3:28: error: template template parameter requires 'class' after the parameter list
template <template <class> requires true class>
                           ^
```

Which compiler should I trust? Is this code grammatically valid?

Comment: Keep in mind that lots of ill-formed programs are legal grammar (e.g., `int x = "";`). I'm not sure whether you're looking for an answer on grammar specifically or whether it's semantically correct as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be legal grammar. A template begins with a [*template-head*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#nt:template-head) which is

> `template` `<` *template-parameter-list* `>` *requires-clause* <sub>opt</sub>

then a [*template-parameter-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#nt:template-parameter-list) can be

> *template-parameter*

where [*template-parameter*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#nt:template-parameter) can be

> *type-parameter*

and then [*type-parameter*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#nt:type-parameter) can be

> *template-head* *type-parameter-key* `...`<sub>opt</sub> *identifier*<sub>opt</sub>

Now this includes *template-head* which allows for a *requires-clause* as mentioned above.